# Интегрированные ресурсы

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Доброго времени суток! Вероятно вопрос глупый, но что-то не могу нагуглить решение. Есть `as3-проект` (во `FlashDevelop`). Ресурс лежить в `/lib`. Конструкция:

```
[Embed(source = "lib/std.png", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
```

Встраивает его в ролик? А как его использовать после этого (скажем засунуть в Спрайт)? Заренее спасибо. Так как есть ощущение, что что-то глобально не так делаю. Или не то ищу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё. Баран признаю.

```
[Embed(source = '../lib/Parallax-scroll-example-layer-0.gif')]
private var layer0Class:Class;
private var layer0:Bitmap = new layer0Class();
```

Дальше всё очевидно.